# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Parameter 0: Type mismatch

Tags: php, api

I am using PHP to connect with SAP2000 (structural analysis software) through API.

I get an error mentioned in the title on this line and i don't know what am i doing wrong?

```
$ret = $SapModel->PointObj->setRestraint("A", $supports);
```

Error:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Parameter 0: Type mismatch.
Stack trace:
#0 C:\...: variant->setRestraint("A", Array)
#1 (main)
```

This is from the SAP2000 API Manual:

---

- VB6 Procedure

  Function SetRestraint(ByVal Name As String, ByRef
  Value() As Boolean, Optional ByVal ItemType As eItemType = object) As
  Long
- Parameters

**Name**

The name of an existing point object or group depending on the value of the ItemType item.

**Value**

This is an array of six restraint values.

```
Value(0) = U1
Value(1) = U2
Value(2) = U3
Value(3) = R1
Value(4) = R2
Value(5) = R3
```

**ItemType**

This is one of the following items in the eItemType enumeration:

```
Object = 0
Group = 1
SelectedObjects = 2
```

If this item is Object, the restraint assignment is made to the point object specified by the Name item.

If this item is Group, the restraint assignment is made to all point objects in the group specified by the Name item.

If this item is SelectedObjects, the restraint assignment is made to all selected point objects and the Name item is ignored.

---

My whole code:
    ApplicationStart();

```
$SapModel=$SapObj->SapModel;
$ret = $SapModel->InitializeNewModel;
$ret = $SapModel->File->NewBlank;

settype($Name, "string");
$ret = $SapModel->PointObj->AddCartesian(0, 0, 0, $Name, "A");
$ret = $SapModel->PointObj->AddCartesian(0, 6, 0, $Name, "B");
$ret = $SapModel->FrameObj->AddByPoint("A", "B", $Name);

$supports = array(
True,
True,
True,
False,
False,
False);

$ret = $SapModel->PointObj->setRestraint("A", $supports);
$ret = $SapModel->PointObj->setRestraint("B", $supports);
?>
```

Comment: var_dump($SapModel); and show the output.

Comment: I took a screenshot, so here is the [image:](http://i.imgur.com/XN9I1fw.png)

Comment: And var_dump($SapObj);  please.

Comment: I get: object(com)#1 (0) {}